# How to set multiple values with additional field in django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-serializer

I have a model which represents a many-to-many table.

serializers.py

```
class WasteFacilityPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=255,
        error_messages={
            "required": "Name is required.",
            "max_length": "Name can be maximum 255 characters.",
        },
    )
    contact_person_name = serializers.CharField(
        required=False,
        max_length=255,
        error_messages={
            "max_length": "Contact person name can be maximum 255 characters.",
        },
    )
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=False,
        max_length=255,
        error_messages={
            "invalid": "Email address not valid.",
            "max_length": "Email can be maximum 255 characters.",
        },
    )
    mobile = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex=r"^\d{10,14}$",
                message="Phone number must be entered in format: '+999999999'. Up to 14 digits allowed.",
            )
        ],
        max_length=15,
        error_messages={
            "required": "Mobile is required.",
            "max_length": "Mobile can be maximum 14 digits.",
        },
    )
    street = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=255,
        error_messages={
            "required": "Street is required.",
            "max_length": "Street can be maximum 255 characters.",
        },
    )
    suite = serializers.CharField(
        required=False,
        max_length=255,
        error_messages={"max_length": "Suite can be maximum 255 characters.",},
    )
    city = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=255,
        error_messages={
            "required": "City is required.",
            "max_length": "City can be maximum 255 characters.",
        },
    )
    zipcode = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=10,
        error_messages={
            "required": "Zipcode is required.",
            "max_length": "Zipcode can be maximum 10 digits.",
        },
    )
    state = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=255,
        error_messages={
            "required": "State is required.",
            "max_length": "State can be maximum 255 characters.",
        },
    )

    material_types = MaterialTypeSerializer(
        required=True,
        many=True,
        error_messages={"required": "Material type is required."},
    )

    class Meta:
        model = WasteFacility
        exclude = []

    def validate_name(self, value):
        waste_facility = WasteFacility.objects

        if self.instance:
            waste_facility = waste_facility.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)

        if waste_facility.filter(name__iexact=value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Waste facility with this name already exists."
            )

        return value

    def validate_email(self, value):
        waste_facility = WasteFacility.objects

        if self.instance:
            waste_facility = waste_facility.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)

        if waste_facility.filter(email__iexact=value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Waste facility with this email already exists."
            )

        return value

    def validate_mobile(self, value):
        if validate_phone_number(value) is None:

            waste_facility = WasteFacility.objects

            if self.instance:
                waste_facility = waste_facility.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)

            if waste_facility.filter(mobile__iexact=value):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    "Waste facility with this phone number already exists."
                )

        return value

    def validate_material_types(self, attrs):
        if len(attrs) == 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("At least one material type is required.")
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                material_types = validated_data.pop("material_types")

                instance = WasteFacility.objects.create(**validated_data)

                for material_type in material_types:
                    material_type = dict(material_type)
                    try:

                        material_type_to_be_added = MaterialType.objects.filter(
                            name=material_type["name"]
                        ).get()

                        WasteFacilityMaterialType.objects.create(
                            waste_facility=instance,
                            material_type=material_type_to_be_added,
                            cost_per_ton=material_type["cost_per_ton"],
                        )

                    except MaterialType.DoesNotExist:
                        raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid material type ")

            return instance
        except DatabaseError as database_error:
            return None

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                material_types = validated_data.pop("material_types")

                instance.name = validated_data["name"]
                instance.contact_person_name = validated_data["contact_person_name"]
                instance.email = validated_data["email"]
                instance.mobile = validated_data["mobile"]
                instance.street = validated_data["street"]
                instance.suite = validated_data["suite"]
                instance.city = validated_data["city"]
                instance.zipcode = validated_data["zipcode"]
                instance.state = validated_data["state"]
                instance.save()

                for material_type in material_types:
                    material_type = dict(material_type)
                    try:

                        material_type_to_be_added = MaterialType.objects.filter(
                            name=material_type["name"]
                        ).get()

                        WasteFacilityMaterialType.objects.create(
                            waste_facility=instance,
                            material_type=material_type_to_be_added,
                            cost_per_ton=material_type["cost_per_ton"],
                        )

                    except MaterialType.DoesNotExist:
                        raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid material type ")

            return instance
        except DatabaseError as database_error:
            return None
```

models.py

```
class MaterialType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = MaterialTypeManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "material_types"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class WasteFacility(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    contact_person_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex=r"^\d{10,14}$",
                message="Phone number must be entered in format: '+999999999'. Up to 14 digits allowed.",
            )
        ],
        max_length=15,
        unique=True,
    )
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    suite = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    material_types = models.ManyToManyField(
        MaterialType,
        through=u"WasteFacilityMaterialType",
        related_name=u"waste_facility_material_type",
    )

    objects = WasteFacilityManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "waste_facilities"


class WasteFacilityMaterialType(models.Model):
    waste_facility = models.ForeignKey(
        WasteFacility,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="waste_facility_material_type",
    )
    material_type = models.ForeignKey(
        MaterialType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="material_type_waste_facility",
    )
    cost_per_ton = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "waste_facility_material_type"
        unique_together = [["waste_facility", "material_type"]]
```

How can I add records to this table when inserting/updating with additional field cost_per_ton so that when a object of material_type is removed from the request the records should be also removed from the table.

Basically how to achieve sync of many many to records with additional fields.

My request looks something like this:

```
{
    "name":"Dade Waste Facility",
    "email":"pritamk@gobiggi.com",
    "mobile":"3054014181",
    "street":"Street 1",
    "city":"Miami",
    "zipcode":"33161",
    "state":"Florida",
    "material_types": [{
        "name": "Metal",
        "cost_per_ton": 20
    },
    {
        "cost_per_ton": 50,
        "name": "Food"
    }]
}
```

Comment: can you add the code of  your views and serializer + you are using e a ForeignKey which is Many-to-one relationships not Many-to-many relationship

Comment: @seif question updated with serializer and model with many to many relationship code. Also if you want to see implementation of create and update waste facility model. check the WasteFacilityPostSerializer the implementation is in its create and update method